# C++ Vector copying works with one vector but doesn't with the other

Tags: c++, vector

This problem is really odd, I can't seem to find anything that causes it.

So here is an assignment operator overloading function, birds and mammals are vectors. (down below are the classes)

```
const Register& Register::operator=(const Register& theOther)
{
    if(this != &theOther)
    {
        this->~Register();               // deleted
        birds.resize(theOther.birds.size());
        mammals.resize(theOther.mammals.size());

        birds=theOther.birds;
        mammals=theOther.mammals;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

(if you find anything that is weird here, that is because I rewrote these lines many times). So the problem is while running, the

> birds.operator=(theOther.birds);

works absolutely fine, every variable is copied properly, but when it reaches the next line, it calls the same vector copying function as with the birds, but **mammals** never gets **theOther.mammals** -es Animal parts (species, etc.). It gets the only mammal parts (predator, etc.). I just don't understand. Below are my classes, and as you can see, they are completely similar at the parts which are important here...

So, the classes

```
class Animal
{
    char* species;
    unsigned int weight;
    char* color;
public:
...
}
```

The bird class

```
class Bird: public Animal
{
    bool singing;
    bool waterfowl;
    unsigned int eggs; 

public:
...
const Bird& operator =(const Bird& theOther);
{
    if(this != &theOther)
    {
        Bird copy(theOther);
        this->setSpecies(copy.getSpecies());
        this->setWeight(copy.getWeight());
        this->setColor(copy.getColor());

        singing = theOther.singing;
        waterfowl = theOther.waterfowl;
        eggs = theOther.eggs;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The mammal class

```
class Mammal: public Animal
{
    bool predator;
    bool oviparous;
public:
...
const Mammal& Mammal::operator =(const Mammal& theOther)
{
    if(this != &theOther)
    {
        Mammal copy(theOther);
        this->setPredator(copy.getPredator());
        this->setOviparous(copy.getOviparous());

        predator = theOther.predator;
        oviparous = theOther.oviparous;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And of course the Register, which has the vectors.

```
class Register
{
    std::vector <Bird> birds;
    std::vector <Mammal> mammals;
    std::vector <Reptile> reptiles;

public:
...
```

edit:

```
Register::Register(const Register& newRegister)
{
    birds = newRegister.birds;
    mammals = newRegister.mammals;
    reptiles = newRegister.reptiles;
}
```

edit2:

```
void Animal::setSpecies(char* _species)
{
    this->species = _species;
}
```

Maybe I'm just too tired to find the mistake that I made. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::string` for species and color? All these copy constructors go away if so. I'm not sure what `setSpecies` looks like, but you're not copying the pointer there.

Comment: `this->~Register()` ermmmmmm

Comment: added `setSpecies` to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated before - don't call the destructor manually.

The reason your mammal `operator=` doesn't copy the species, weight and color while your bird `operator=` does is because the mammal version doesn't have the code that sets those value. The bird operator has these lines:

```
    this->setSpecies(copy.getSpecies());
    this->setWeight(copy.getWeight());
    this->setColor(copy.getColor());
```

the mammal operator does not.

Either copy those lines into the mammal operator or, better still, write a method of animal that does it and call it from both bird and mammal operators.

I am also not sure why you need to make a copy before calling `getSpecies` etc, you should be able to call it on the original `theOther` parameter.

Comment: You are totally right, I can't believe that I didn't see those lines missing... I'm going to use those other tips too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behaviour. After you call `this->~Register();`, you must not access any members of `this`. You should simply remove that line, and everything will be fine (although perhaps not exception safe).

If you want strong exception safety, you should implement `operator=` using the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
const Register& Register::operator=(Register theOther)
{
    std::swap(*this, theOther);
    return *this;
}
```

Furthermore, the `operator=` in your subclasses should call through to the `operator=` in the super-class. You can do this manually with a call to `Animal::operator=`, or you can again use copy-and-swap for strong exception safety.

```
Mammal& Mammal::operator=(const Mammal& theOther)
{
    if(this != &theOther)
    {
        static_cast<Animal&>(*this) = theOther; //Call Animal::operator=
        predator = theOther.predator;
        oviparous = theOther.oviparous;
    }
    return *this;
}

//Or use:
Mammal& Mammal::operator=(Mammal theOther)
{
    std::swap(*this, theOther);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Well hang on a minute; copy-and-swap is not a magic bullet. The OP would still need to _implement_ that swappage. You haven't really suggested much more than, in effect, adding an extra layer of function call indirection!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Swappage is automatically implemented as long as there are appropriate move constructors. (And there is nothing to suggest that there wouldn't be). Furthermore, I have suggested removing `this->~Register();`, which is sufficient to fix the problem if strong exception safety is not desired.

Comment: Actually I put in this->~Register(); after I got the error, because I saw something like that in a forum, but it didn't help.
And this swap... it failed. The program stopped working, "  Exception Code: c00000fd" In debug mode I just can't step over it, and when I stepped into, some steps later It accessed my Register copy constructor (I'm putting it to the end of the post).

Comment: @nandoo: You should provide a complete, compilable, but minimal example. There is nothing in your snippets that shouldn't work (once you've made the modifications that I've suggested). The only other problem that I can imagine is that you are messing up the management of the memory referenced by the raw pointers in `Animal`. As suggested in the comments on your question, you should try replacing `char* species;` and `char* color;` with `std::string` members.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it, just `char* species` is in there so many times... it's going to take a while.

Comment: It makes a lot of trouble, because I'm comparing that char* and reading into it from files and stuff.. whoa.